# Simple question about Cantor's theorem and ZFC axioms

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Does any ZFC axiom prevents a function $f$ from a set $X$ to its power set $P(X)$, since the cardinality of $P(x)$ is strictly greater than the cardinality of $X$?

Comment: what do you mean prevent?
you could map everything to one element

Comment: No, there are lots of functions from a set to its power set. What there isn’t is a **surjective** function from a set to its power set. And this holds in ZF, you don’t need Choice.